# Declare a string in Web.Config file

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Look at this code piece please:

```
string dir = "~/parkingTicket/files/"+ID_TextBox.Text;
try
{
   _path = Server.MapPath(dir) + ID_TextBox.Text + "_" + _file.FileName;
   EnsureDirectoriesExist(dir);
   _file.SaveAs(_path);
}
```

i want to declare **(dir)** in web.config, how can i do that?
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in appSetting node liket his

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="dir" value="parkingTicket/files"/>
  </appSettings>
```

you can read it in code file like

```
string dir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dir"].ToString();
```