# Best way to for handling paths

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In a project, I have 2-3 classes having paths to my local filesystem folders. Like below:

Class 1:

```
 private static string UPLOAD_ROOT = "~/Uploads/";
 private static string IMAGES_FOLDER = "Images";
```

Class 2:

```
 private static string UPLOAD_ROOT = "~/Uploads/";
 private static string PSD_FOLDER = "Generated PhotoShop PSDs";
```

So, As we can see, UPLOAD_ROOT is repeating wherever I need it. I want to keep these paths in a single file. How should I do that?

Possible solution that I can see is to put these files in a static class and use it as below:

```
public static class PathSettings
{
   public static string UPLOAD_ROOT = "~/Uploads/";
   public static string IMAGES_FOLDER = "Images";
   public static string PSD_FOLDER = "Generated PhotoShop PSDs";

}
```

Then using this class as below:

```
file.SaveAs(PathSettings.UPLOAD_ROOT + filename);
```

How should I store it then? Is using static class is the **best** solution? What is used in CMSes?

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static class with constants is perfectly valid. The main downside to this approach is that the application would need to recompiled in the event that the directory is moved.

So, you could consider moving the constants out to the application's `web.config` file. When you need to figure out the value, just pull it out of the `web.config` file as illustrated in this answer:

[Declare a string in Web.Config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152765/declare-a-string-in-web-config-file)

(Not sure if the `~` is allowed in the `web.config` string. It would be easy enough to tack it on after reading it.)

Edit:

CMSs generally use configuration files to store paths such as these, and then a common static library is used to pull back the path information. Generally there is some UI for the administrator to change the paths, which in turn edits the file full of path info.

Comment: No..surely nope..My `web.config` is already complicated. I dont want to put so many `keys` in it.

Comment: Then create your own file if you want to and parse that thing manually

Comment: What do you mean by `Configuration Files` used in CMSs? Files like `web.config`?

Comment: Web config is the best-practice approach. You can split it into multiple files if it gets too big as a single file.

Comment: Generally CMSs try to be platform independent, so they don't use `web.config` because that would be specific to IIS. They might use `paths.config` and have a class that parses the values in there.

Comment: @debracey `paths.config` seems to be great..thanks...

Comment: @debracey, if you're writing a CMS in ASP.NET you'll have web.config, whether it is in IIS or Apache with Mono. You can't write a program that is agnostic to the framework and language it is written in.

Answer (score 2):

Put them as settings in your web.config. This can be done through an editor in visual studio: Right-click project, select properties. Select the "Settings" tab on the left. Alternately, in the "Properties" folder under the project (in Solution Explorer) there should be a settings file which you can double-click.

You can access the values in here using Properties.Settings.Default.WhateverSettingName.

Also, for extra credit, create a Path object from your string, and use that in the rest of your system.

Comment: I am not getting `create a Path object from your string, and use that in the rest of your system.`? Can you explain it ?

Comment: System.IO.Path is a class specifically designed for dealing with filesystem paths. The MSDN documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx

You get a lot of methods for validating the path, and extracting information from it such as does it point to a file or a folder, is it an absolute path or a relative path. It will also do stuff like converting a relative path to a fully-qualified path based on what the current working directory is etc. It's a good thing to use.

Answer (score 1):

if these constant values are changing based on OS, Language etc, You better go for resources files to store the constants.

when you generate path or URI from strings better to use methods of [`Path Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w.aspx) and [`Uri Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx)